# UWP: Load page from DLL

Tags: uwp, prism, portable-class-library, uwp-xaml

I have created a "Blank Application (Universal Windows)" using VS2015 (with Update 3).

I then added a "Class Library (Universal Windows)" project to the same solution and moved the MainPage.xaml from the "Blank Application" project to a "Views" folder within the "Class Library" project (I also changed the namespace within both the XAML and CS to include the "Views").

Finally, I referenced the "Class Library" project from the "Blank Application" project, added a "using" for the "Views" namespace to the app.xaml.cs and tried to run the "Blank Application" project.

It fails with a System.AccessViolationException: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt".

Both the "Blank Application" project and the "Class Library" project are targeting Universal Windows with a target version of "10.0 (10586)" and a minimum version of "10.0 (10240)". Both projects also reference PRISM as well as a "Portable Class Library" targeting ".NET Framework 4.5", "ASP.NET Core 1.0", "Windows 8", "Windows Phone 8.1", "Windows Phone Silverlight 8", "Xamarin.Android", "Xamarin.iOS" and "Xamarin.iOS (Classic)" - the same list of targets as is present in Prism.Core.

Am I trying to do something that is not allowed? All I want is to be able to break down my views into separate DLL's based upon functionality group.

Comment: Can you show us how you navigate? Using Prism?

Comment: @Bart, not using PRISM yet - just added as a reference so that I can start using it. Only change to the startup is adding the Views namespace to the app.xaml.cs so that the default startup (rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);) code runs. I have subsequently removed all references to PRISM and the problem persists.

Comment: Wow!  It's nearly 2019 and Microsoft have yet to fix this.  Do they expect every UWP developer to not know about good software practices?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the issue. This is intresting, I was about to move all my XAML Pages to a DLL so that i have a clean solution and build different application layers and saw this question today. This raised a red flag for me so started looking for documentation and ways of working around this. After 3 hrs of research, i thought instead of searching online, find a way of doing it myself and came up with Creating a content control on my MainPage from UWP Solution.

```
<Page
    x:Class="App8.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App8"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <ContentControl x:Name="MainControl" />
</Page>
```

And this is my Code Behind.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainControl.Content = new ClassLibrary1.MainPage();
    }
}
```